# spring data ehcache returning stale data in multi node environment

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, ehcache, spring-data-jpa

With the below code, ehcache is not reflecting the latest data in a multi node (JVM) environment. Instead spring data repository method's return the stale data. Whats missing from this code to return the latest data? 
`findByName` method from the below Foo JPA repository returns stale data. On first call, it caches the data. In subsequent calls (after timeToLiveSeconds elapsed) I still get the same cached data even though there was a change to the Entity's data in DB. I expect that `timeToLiveSeconds` will cause the cache to expire and reload the data on subsequent call.
On node-1 which receives the db update call, cache is updated as expected. i.e `findByName` method returns the latest data. The same call on another node returns stale data. (even after timeToLiveSeconds elapsed)

```java
//Entity class
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "foo_content") 
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
class Foo {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "test")
@GenericGenerator(name = "test", strategy = "sequence",
 parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "hibernate_seq") })
private int primaryKey;
@NotNull private String name;
private int version;
@NotNull
@Lob
@Column(table = "foo_content")
private String content;
}

//Foo JPA repository:
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {
@Query("SELECT foo FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.name = ?1 AND foo.version = (SELECT MAX(t.version) from Foo t WHERE t.name = ?1)")
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")}) Foo findByName(String name);
}
```

ehcache.xml

```xml
<cache name="com.blah.blah.Foo" timeToLiveSeconds="300" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false"/>
```

jpaPropertyMap properties

```xml
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">DISABLE_SELECTIVE</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop> 
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">META-INF/com/blah/blah/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug as discussed in [this forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=979125) thread and the corresponding ticket is closed sighting lack of testcase as per [Jira](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4080)

So its a bug which still exists. A work around might be to extend `UpdateTimestampsCache` class to override `isUpToDate` method. I might try this soon and post updates.

**Update:** Hibernate version I use is 3.5.2 (I agree its old). This version does not allow to plugin custom `UpdateTimestampsCache` as per [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4055) thread. As of now I have no plans to upgrade to latest hibernate version due to application impact.